# What function or method can I use to equally distribute a workload

Tags: algorithms, math, distribution

This is more of mathematical question than an algorithmic one; nevertheless it will be implemented in php.

I have an array of N tasks. Each task has taken t time to complete(e.g. task 1 has taken 5 hours to complete.) Now, in order to review that these tasks were completed correctly, I have to assign a certain number of users U to review each of them. Each user will be assigned a certain number of tasks, ideally, with each user having roughly the same amount of hours assigned as the other.

E.G.  There are 10 tasks. task 1 took 4 hours, task 2 took 18 hours, task 3 took 6 hours...etc... totaling 80 hours.

There are 8 users.  If each of the 8 users is to ideally have the same amount of hours (some users get more, yet less lengthier tasks, some users get less, yet lengthier tasks), what is a good way to automatically sort assign the tasks?

Comment: You need to look in to [Knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) Algorithms.

Comment: @Mchl: belongs in a closevote

Comment: As the implementation isn't relevant to the question at hand, I vote to close this as off-topic, but relating to [Math.SE]. It could use a bit of rewording too. After @John understands the algorithm involved, he can take some time to mess around in code, and ask questions specifically related to the code involved on [SO].

Comment: _If_ the problem you are talking about is actually servers doing any amount of distributed work, I would let them 'pull' tasks rather then 'push' tasks. Requires polling after every single task to get the next one, and no 'queue' at the users end. It would however not necessarily mean every server does the same amount of work, just probably as fast as can be done. Disregard this comment is you really need a fair distribution ;)

Comment: To complete your description, you need to specify: How many users could review a given task (min, max).

Comment: This might be better asked on [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com/). As it's been migrated once is't not a good idea to migrate it again.

Comment: @ChrisF i really don't see how this is off topic, algorithm discussions are explicitly listed as on topic.

Comment: @Ryathal - actually algorithm questions are also on topic for Stack Overflow, but at least 4 people voted to migrate it here. It picked up flags which is why I acted.

Comment: @ChrisF all I could see is what appeared to be a unilateral decision by you, to close which is why I commented, what SO decides is their business, my comment seems more confrontational than I intended.

Comment: @Ryathal - if you'd followed the link in the "migrated from" message below you would have seen the question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree with S.Robins. Putting the data in queue will also avid cherry picking and partiality... We also need to make sure that once the agent logs out we can have the case routed back to the queue...

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm shown below provides a solution. I have not tested it throughly, but it should give you an idea. It could only be used only if the sum(resources available time) >= sum(required task review time).

The process starts by examining Task1's required review time and resource 1 availalble time. If the available time is less than or equal the time required by the task, the intersection cell of T1, U1 is filled with the the number of hours that would either fulfill the required review time or the available time for user 1.

Next, we go to task 2 and repeat the process.

If the allocation exhausts a given resource's available time, logic moves to the next resource.

The iterations should stop when this condition is violated or when all resources have been allocated.

In the image below, step 0 is the initial step. I have used an Orange color to show the changes at each step, hoping you can discover the process.

**Note:**

This process is biased to the way users are listed from left to right and does not distribute work evenly across users. That is, one user may work harder than the rest just because he/she appears before the others.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of the [open shop scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling#Jobs_consisting_of_multiple_operations) problem. The problem is NP-complete, so you'll want to apply some heuristic, such as the one described in the Wikipedia or perhaps one of the genetic algorithms in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.29.4699&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may be over-thinking this. Arrange tasks in a simple queue and order according to priority. Having each user take the first task available should be enough.  Longer tasks might take longer to review, and short ones less time, therefore the order in which users appear to collect the next task will change as they finish the previous task and come forward for the next.  This doesn't really need to be too complicated.

Pre-allocating tasks can have some serious drawbacks.  This is basically a push system, and it  tends to result in "waste" more often than not.  Implementing a pull system would be much more efficient, and less wasteful in terms of scheduling and resources, as you won't end up needing to manage synchronization issues if work estimates are either wrong, or become interrupted by changing circumstances within the team.